# Make static variable accessible to JLabel?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I'm playing around with JFrames for fun and can't quite get a panel to display a static variable. I'd appreciate any help. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JButtonTester
{
    static int counter = 0;
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        class ClickCounter implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                counter++;
                System.out.println("Congratulations, you clicked a button " + counter + " time(s)! This might just be your greatest accomplishment");
            }
        }
        class ClickDecrement implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                counter--;
                System.out.println("Congratulations, you clicked a button " + counter + " time(s)! This might just be your greatest accomplishment");
            }
        }
        JFrame firstFrame = new JFrame();
        JLabel counter = new JLabel("Count: " + counter);
        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();

        JButton firstButton = new JButton("Click me to increase your count!");
        firstPanel.add(firstButton);
        ActionListener firstListener = new ClickCounter();
        firstButton.addActionListener(firstListener);

        JButton secondButton = new JButton("Click me to decrease your count!");
        firstPanel.add(secondButton);
        ActionListener secondListener = new ClickDecrement();
        secondButton.addActionListener(secondListener);

        firstFrame.add(firstPanel);
        firstFrame.setSize(200, 120);
        firstFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        firstFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The variable I'm trying to access is "counter."

Comment: error message from BlueJ: "variable counter may not have been initialized"
on this line: JLabel counter = new JLabel("Count: " + counter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things you need to do:

1. Rename your fields: you have two variables named `counter`.
2. Second, you'll want to move your `JLabel` above the `actionPerformed` method and declare it `final` so you can access it from within the `actionPerformed` method.
3. I don't see where you added the `JLabel` to the panel, so I added that line

This should do what you want:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JButtonTester {

    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JLabel counter_label = new JLabel();
        class ClickCounter implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                counter++;
                System.out.println("Congratulations, you clicked a button " + counter + " time(s)! This might just be your greatest accomplishment");
                counter_label.setText("Count: " + counter);
            }
        }
        class ClickDecrement implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                counter--;
                System.out.println("Congratulations, you clicked a button " + counter + " time(s)! This might just be your greatest accomplishment");
                counter_label.setText("Count: " + counter);
            }
        }
        JFrame firstFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstPanel.add(counter_label);

        JButton firstButton = new JButton("Click me to increase your count!");
        firstPanel.add(firstButton);
        ActionListener firstListener = new ClickCounter();
        firstButton.addActionListener(firstListener);

        JButton secondButton = new JButton("Click me to decrease your count!");
        firstPanel.add(secondButton);
        ActionListener secondListener = new ClickDecrement();
        secondButton.addActionListener(secondListener);

        firstFrame.add(firstPanel);
        firstFrame.setSize(200, 120);
        firstFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        firstFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a static variable from another class would mean to proceed the variable name with the name of the class since static means that it is a class variable. Therefore, since counter is a static variable of the class JButtonTester, to access counter from another class you would say JButtonTester.counter

```
JLabel counter = new JLabel("Count: " + JButtonTester.counter);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick and super helpful response, Josh. It worked! I'm not so sure why this was necessary, though. Isn't the variable within the scope of the main method?

Comment: This solution works because you have two variables named `counter`. One is an `int`, another is `JLabel`. If you renamed your label to `counter_label` it would work as well.

Comment: I will, as soon as I am permitted to (3 minutes)
@ryvantage, thanks a bunch.

I have another question: how can I make the actionListener methods in ClickCounter and ClickDecrement update the JLabel?

Comment: you need to use the `setText()` method in `JLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

You're line here is wrong

```
JLabel counter = new JLabel("Count: " + counter);
```

counter is the reference to the JLabel you are creating, use a different variable name